# While creating Cross account role using terraform getting error Error: Error asking for user input: Cannot parse value for variable policy_arns

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Am trying to create cross account role using terraform while giveing the policy name as input getting error *Error: Error asking for user input: Cannot parse value for variable policy_arns*

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "cross_account" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["${var.principal_arns}"]
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "cross_account_role" {
  name               = "${var.name}"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.cross_account_assume_role_policy.json}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "cross_account_role" {
  count = "${length(var.policy_arns)}"

  role       = "${aws_iam_role.cross_account_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${element(var.policy_arns, count.index)}"
}
```

```
variable "name" {
  type        = "string"
  description = "Name of the role being created."
}

variable "principal_arns" {
  type        = "list"
  description = "ARNs of accounts, groups, or users with the ability to assume this role."
}

variable "policy_arns" {
  type        = "list"
  description = "List of ARNs of policies to be associated with the created IAM role"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables passed with either `-var foo=bar` command line flag or as the environment variable `TF_VAR_foo=bar` can only be [literal strings](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/variables.html#booleans):

> - Variables specified via the -var command line flag will be literal strings "true" and "false", so care should be taken to explicitly use "0" or "1".
> - Variables specified with the TF_VAR_ environment variables will be literal string values, just like -var.

If you want to be able to use list variables then you will either need to define these ahead of time in a [`terraform.tfvars` file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files) or other [vars file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/variables.html#variable-files) or you could use the [`split()` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#split-delim-string-) to take a separated string and turn it into a list:

```
variable "string_list" {
  type = "string"
}

locals {
  list_list = "${split(",", var.string_list)}"
}

output "list_list" {
  value = ["${local.list_list}"]
}
```